# R Studio: How to load a variable into the Global Environment by running a Knitr document

Tags: r, knitr

When I run a knitr document in R Studio, a variable is assigned. I can see this from the generated PDF-file.

Although this variable is not loading into my Global Environment.

My working directory is set in the knitr document. In R studio I use the same working directory.

Is there a method to load the variables into my Global Environment by using knitr?

Thank you.

This is the code:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r section1, echo=TRUE}

getwd()

# set the URL for the download
wwwTrain <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv"
training <- read.csv(url(wwwTrain))
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually render your document within the global environment by executing this in the RStudio console:

```
rmarkdown::render("my_document.Rmd", envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

I do this frequently and wrote an [RStudio Addin](https://github.com/jeffjjohnston/RStudioConsoleRender) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff. The code and Addin runs perfect! regards, Marcel